# Android: Cast SDK v3 CastOptionsProvider not detected in release build

Tags: android, casting, chromecast

I've correctly declared CastOptiponsProvider manifest.xml

```
        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.OPTIONS_PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME"
        android:value="org.lao.yao.kd.cast.CastOptionsProvider" />
```

Anyway I got this error message only when I build app for release:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.lao.yao.kd.cast.CastOptionsProvider
```

Thi is my CastOptionsProvider class:

```
public class CastOptionsProvider implements OptionsProvider {

@Override
public CastOptions getCastOptions(Context context) {
    NotificationOptions notificationOptions = new NotificationOptions.Builder()
            .setActions(Arrays.asList(MediaIntentReceiver.ACTION_SKIP_NEXT,
                    MediaIntentReceiver.ACTION_TOGGLE_PLAYBACK,
                    MediaIntentReceiver.ACTION_STOP_CASTING), new int[]{1, 2})
            .setTargetActivityClassName(ExpandedControlsActivity.class.getName())
            .build();
    CastMediaOptions mediaOptions = new CastMediaOptions.Builder()
            .setImagePicker(new ImagePickerImpl())
            .setNotificationOptions(notificationOptions)
            .setExpandedControllerActivityClassName(ExpandedControlsActivity.class.getName())
            .build();
    return new CastOptions.Builder()
            .setReceiverApplicationId(MyJsonConfig.getPrefString(MyJsonConfig.KEY_CHROMECAST_RECEIVER_ID, context) )
            .setCastMediaOptions(mediaOptions)
            .build();
}

@Override
public List<SessionProvider> getAdditionalSessionProviders(Context appContext) {
    return null;
}

private static class ImagePickerImpl extends ImagePicker {

    @Override
    public WebImage onPickImage(MediaMetadata mediaMetadata, int type) {
        if ((mediaMetadata == null) || !mediaMetadata.hasImages()) {
            return null;
        }
        List<WebImage> images = mediaMetadata.getImages();
        if (images.size() == 1) {
            return images.get(0);
        } else {
            if (type == ImagePicker.IMAGE_TYPE_MEDIA_ROUTE_CONTROLLER_DIALOG_BACKGROUND) {
                return images.get(0);
            } else {
                return images.get(1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I also use proguard for my release build.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've run into this issue before with Proguard and external libraries (especially Google's stuff). I used the following in the `proguard-rules.pro` file:

```
-keep class org.lao.yao.kd.cast.CastOptionsProvider { *; }
```

Also your CastIntentReceiver.

```
-keep class org.lao.yao.kd.cast.CastIntentReceiver { *; }
```

For good measure, I also add these lines:

```
-keep class android.support.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.** { *; }
-keep class java.nio.file.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you specify the corect class path in manifest
for CastOptionsProvider

```
      <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.OPTIONS_PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME"
        android:value="com.your.path.CastOptionsProvider" />
```